# How to use step object in Codeception v2.1

Tags: codeception

I'm a starter to learn Codeception and I found that officical guide didn't tell me anything about the step object.

The change log of version 2.1 says

> all support classes moved to tests/_support by default. Actors, Helpers, PageObjects, StepObjects, GroupObjects to follow PSR-4 naming style

So anybody can tell me how to use step object in the latest version? Or give me a simple example about that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here should be what you are looking for: 
http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#StepObjects